# Passing arguments in bloc flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin, bloc

I'm using Bloc pattern to manage the states of my application , I'm fetching some data from Api , and everything is set up so far , i got stuck in how can i pass a mealID ( the argument i want to pass in bloc to fetch the next api call . i need some help please , Thank you in advance  .

- This is my whole bloc code

```
 // bloc events 
 enum FoodEvent {category,food}
```

```
// bloc state
class FoodState {

}

class InitialLoading extends FoodState{

}
class Loading extends FoodState {}

class Error extends FoodState {
String error;
Error(this.error);
}

class Success extends FoodState {
CategoryModel? categoryModel;
Success(this.categoryModel);
}

class FoodSuccess extends FoodState {
FoodModel? foodModel;
FoodSuccess(this.foodModel);
}
```

```
  // Main Bloc class 
  class FoodBloc extends Bloc<FoodEvent,FoodState> {

  FoodRepository foodRepository = FoodRepository(authService: AuthService());

  FoodBloc() : super(InitialLoading()){
        on<FoodEvent>(_onFetchEvent);
  }

    Future<void> _onFetchEvent(FoodEvent event, Emitter<FoodState> emit,) async {

       switch(event){
         case FoodEvent.category:
           emit(Loading());
           try {
             var categoryModel = await foodRepository.getCategory();
             emit(Success(categoryModel));
           } catch (e) {
             emit(Error(e.toString()));
           }
           break;

         case FoodEvent.food:
           emit(Loading());
           try {
             /// Basically i need o pass mealID which i should receive and pass here from screen
             var food = await foodRepository.getFood("1252");
             emit(FoodSuccess(food));
           } catch (e) {
             emit(Error(e.toString()));
           }
           break;
       }
  }



}
```

- Class where i init bloc and show data in ui

```
  class DetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  String mealID;
  DetailsScreen({Key? key,required this.mealID}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DetailsScreen> createState() => _DetailsScreenState();
}

class _DetailsScreenState extends State<DetailsScreen> {
   late FoodBloc foodBloc;
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Here i initialize my bloc 
    foodBloc = BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context);
    foodBloc.add(FoodEvent.food);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    foodBloc.close();
    super.dispose();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing argument from the UI depends on your usecases, you can pass using the event or updating your state with the value

You may also consider changing your event to the recommended class based

```
abstract class FoodEvent extends Equatable {
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [];
}

class CategoryFetched extends FoodEvent {}

class FoodFetched extends FoodEvent {
  FoodFetched(this.mealId);

  final String mealId;
  @override
  List<Object> get props => [mealId];
}
```

So while adding event here just pass the MealId

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // Here i initialize my bloc 
    foodBloc = BlocProvider.of<FoodBloc>(context);
    foodBloc.add(FoodFetched(mealId);
    super.didChangeDependencies();
}
```

And your bloc code can be simplified to this:

```
class FoodBloc extends Bloc<FoodEvent,FoodState> {

  FoodRepository foodRepository = FoodRepository(authService: AuthService());

  FoodBloc() : super(InitialLoading()){
       on<CategoryFetched>(_onCategoryFetched);
       on<FoodFetched>(_onFoodFetched);
  }

  Future<void> _onFoodFetched(FoodFetched event, Emitter<FoodState> emit) async {
   try {
     var food = await foodRepository.getFood(event.mealId);
     emit(FoodSuccess(food));
   } catch (e) {
     emit(Error(e.toString()));
   }
 }

  Future<void> _onCategoryFetched(CategoryFetched event, Emitter<FoodState> emit) async {
  try {
    var categoryModel = await foodRepository.getCategory();
    emit(Success(categoryModel));
  } catch (e) {
    emit(Error(e.toString()));
  }
 }    
}
```

Comment: No i just want to be sure of how the ui is structured

Comment: okay i will check

Comment: Thank you for the answer , that makes more sense , now this update , the code in side the main bloc class would also break since i'm using the switch to check for the event , should i handle each request seperately now !

Comment: yes i will add the bloc code shortly

Comment: the answer has been updated with the bloc code as well

Comment: for this line of code :  const GetFood(this.mealId); , it is supposed to be the constructor of the FoodFetched class , it should be named FoodFetched() as well i guess and it does not allow to declare it as a const !!

Comment: yes that is a typo sorry i am editing the code on stack overflow directly, you can recheck

Comment: Thank you for updating the code , i appreciate the time and effort for that , this is exactly what i needed

Comment: Mate , i have just a side question regarding best practices of using bloc , do you think for each screen i create where i need to fetch , i should create its own bloc , because you know if you have a big project with lot of requests , this can accumulate lot of requests in the same bloc and become les s readable , what is your thought on this , Thank you ?

Comment: not really consider creating a bloc per feature

Comment: Yeah that's what i have done , for example i have Screen A and Screen B , for screen A i create a bloc and different one for Screen  B , did i understand you correcly !